# How do I apply filter in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am using :

**Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature**

It works fine, but whenever I load my store data

```
tablePanel.store.loadData(..)
```

the filters are not respected. The columns are visually selected as filtered (ie. greyed out), but all the rows are shown instead of the filtered subset of rows.

Here is the bug trapped in a JSFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/oliverwatkins/7hbt79bj/4/

To reproduce my problem :

- Select column filter on Name, to the value 'foo'
- Now only one row should show (the foo row)
- Now click on Reset.
- The filter is set to only show 'foo', but it shows 'bar' as well.

I know there is a method which removes filters :

```
grid.store.clearFilter();
```

I am looking for a method like this :

```
grid.store.applyFilters();
```

So I can execute it after I refresh the data in my table.

**** UPDATE ****

If I dig a bit deeper I can see that in the table panel there is a filter string being set.

**tablePanel --> filters --> filters --> items --> [1] --> inputItem --> value = 'mySearchString'**

However that is the filters on the tablePanel. If I look at the tablePanel-->store instead, I find filters with no items set :

**tablePanel --> store --> filters --> filters --> items --> [0]**

It is almost as if there are two different filtering systems at play here which are not communicating with each other.

And what makes things all even more infuriating is that store has a **filter** method, and grid does not have a filter method.

```
grid.store.filter(); //method exists

grid.filter(); //crashes
```

puzzling..

Comment: If the column(s) show that they are being filtered, but the results don't, then perhaps the filter values aren't being passed to your server correctly (assuming you are using remote filtering).

Comment: not using remote filtering

Comment: Well, even with local filtering, if a filter is active and has a value, it should be applied when the store is refreshed. Do the filters work if you activate one using it's menu in the column menu?

Comment: hmmm yeah it works fine. its just the loading of the store. Do I need to do something like store.refresh() after doing a store.loadData()?

Comment: Looking at the source code of `loadData`, it appears it checks if `filterOnLoad` is set to true, and if so, it calls the `filter` method. I know this is using the default store filtering, but perhaps the `FiltersFeature` makes use of it too. So, you could try adding `filterOnLoad: true` and (I assume this is already set) `remoteFilter: false` to your store configuration.

Comment: I tried filterOnLoad: true and remoteFilter:false on store and it doesnt work :( I also tried store.filter() which although the method exists does nothing to what I see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hbt79bj/5/) and came up with a solution that sets the values after store load. After `grid.store.loadData` I added this code that reapplies the filters one by one.

```
var filterData = grid.filters.getFilterData();
Ext.Array.each(filterData, function(filter){
    grid.filters.filters.getByKey(filter.field).setValue(filter.data.value)
})
```

Comment: a bit annoying with the 1 second lag... but I'll give it to you :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that grid filters feature creates an interface to the underlying store filtering mechanism. If you bypass the feature interface and go directly down to the store, filters do not know about it and get confused.

Therefore, use only API defined by [FiltersFeature](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature) and everything should work as expected. For example, to clear filters, use:

```
 grid.filters.clearFilters()
```

Comment: yes, but I don't see any method like grid.filters.applyFilters().

Comment: There are [addFilters](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature-method-addFilters) and [addFilter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature-method-addFilter) methods. Don't they do?

Comment: yes they add filters. But I already have filters added and nothing is happening. (see above). Its like the store filter and the grid filters are not talking to each other.

Comment: Yes, it may be a bug in Ext or the application. Can you prepare a working showcase at https://fiddle.sencha.com? I'd take a look.

Comment: trying to, but I don't know how to import the FiltersFeature. (See my latest question on StackOverflow)

Comment: I'm bemused now, I thought you use grid with filters feature already, don't you?

Comment: yes. i use it, but I had never done a loaddata with a column filter set before. I need to get a runnable example but I don't know how to import the FiltersFeature in my jsfiddle.

Comment: jsfiddle or sencha fiddle? I haven't tried but I would suppose that Filters Feature should already be a part of sencha fiddle.

Comment: sencha fiddle also doesnt work : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8j5 it can't find the filters feature

Comment: Hmm, it should work. At least [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/878) works.

Comment: You have the FiltersFeature as a Fiddle Resource. Not sure how to add a resource in SenchaFiddle. Seems pretty confusing.

Comment: @ Saki : my bounty expires in 4 days. Just sayin' ;)