# Applying numeric filter in extjs not working

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am trying to apply a numeric filter to a numeric column in a grid using the **filterfeature** in extjs. I do this by setting a values on my filter using filterdata stored in the grid.

```
var filterData = tablePanel.filters.getFilterData();
Ext.Array.each(filterData, function (filter) {

    try {
        var aFilter = tablePanel.filters.filters.getByKey(filter.field)
        aFilter.setValue(filter.data.value)
    }
    catch (err) {
        Util.logError('err ' + err)
    }
})
```

The construct looks a bit weird, but it is a hack which solves this bug :

[How do I apply filter in ExtJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138025/how-do-i-apply-filter-in-extjs)

This works perfectly if my filters are just plain old string filters, but when I have a numeric filter it throws an exception with this message :

> message: "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'lt' in 19938" stack:
>   (...)

The error is thrown on this line :

`aFilter.setValue(filter.data.value)`

But the objects in question look OK :

**aFilter**

[image]

**filter**

[image]

Why can't I apply numeric filters?

Answer (score 1):

To filter numeric values. you have to provide comparison operator
(lt , gt, eq)

e.g to filter id which equals 3

```
var f =  insidegrid.filters.getFilter('id');
f.setValue({eq:3D});
f.setActive;
```